# How do I generate Laravel 4 URL with index.php?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel 4. I am trying to generate a URL using the URL helpers. There is a function called `url()`. It gives me a URL. But it doesn't add index.php to it.

I want a URL with index.php in it. I cannot use `route()` function because I am using `Route::controller('/', 'SiteController');` I don't want to use `action()` because if there is no `index.php` it will not generate a URL with `index.php`.

Comment: Routing in laravel does not use direct files like "index.php" - I'm afraid that you are probably trying to do it wrong. Can you give me an example of where this index.php is in your file system and what are its contents?

Comment: I want to generate a url to an action of a controller

Comment: like if there is an action called getIndex in the SiteController

Comment: I want a ulr like http://l4/public/index.php/site/index

Comment: @Scopey I hope my reply helps

Comment: ...why would you want to display index.php? Those days are long gone...?

Comment: *I want to generate a url to an action of a controller* Why on Earth you need `index.php` for that? If do need a url to an action you can use [`action()`](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls)

Comment: I told you why I don't want to use action() function.

Comment: See http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls and http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes

Comment: I have already seen them. Still clueless.

Comment: What is the point of keeping the index.php, really?

Comment: no point, i have removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) index.php is where the "app" starts and launches.

2) .htaccess rewrites the URL for u.

3) the whole point of URL() is to provide the BASE url of your domain back so that you dont need to hardcode it - therefore you are using it wrong.

4) the only time index.php is there is if .htaccess is not rewriting or not accepted (ie in yahoo share hosting basically) therefor eyou can achieve your index.php/site/index.

Comment: remove .htaccess from the root of the app, thats all.